# Gravity on a upward moving object

Tags: gravity, forces, mathematical-physics, newtonian-gravity

I know I should have listened to my teacher in physics class but I didn't. I need help on a thing I am trying to do for a game.

I want to be able to calculate Gravity pushing down on a object over a certain amount of time. (I want the object to slow down to a stop and then go back down due to gravity).

I've been looking on the internet and I guess I'm not using the right search terms. So I am hoping that this fine community can help me.

*The object(Player) is only moving upward. The Player is not moving forward or anything. Just Up

Given the initial velocity, how do I compute the motion (position, velocity) of the object as a function of time?

Comment: You could use $F_g = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$, Newton's law of universal gravitation.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Object A is going Upward at 8 speed and I want the object to slow down and drop over time due to gravity. I want to be able to calculate it in code.

Comment: You might be looking for Newton's second law, $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$, where $\vec{a}$ the time derivative of velocity.

Comment: search the internet for "projectile motion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  float position = 0, velocity = 8, time, timeStep = 0.01;
  float g = 9.8;
  for(time = 0; velocity > -10; time+=timeStep) {
    velocity = velocity - timeStep * g;
    position = position + velocity * timeStep;
    printf("time %f; velocity %f; position %f\n", time, velocity, position);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This implements a simple integration of the equations of motion:

$$v = \frac{dx}{dt}\\
a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

I made the time step very small: you can get away with bigger steps (takes less time). Also I keep the loop going until the velocity has reached a certain downward value: you can use any other criteria (time, position, etc).

**UPDATE** As Johannes pointed out, you get slightly more accurate results (even when you use larger time steps) when you use the *average velocity during a time step* to compute the next position. This leads to a small change in code:. Below, I show both the old and the new calculation side by side - as you can see, when the time step is coarser, the new method continues to give good results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  float position = 0, velocity = 8, time, timeStep = 0.1;
  float newposition = 0, oldvelocity;;
  float g = 9.8;
  for(time = 0; velocity > -10; time+=timeStep) {
    oldvelocity = velocity;
    velocity = velocity - timeStep * g;
    position = position + velocity * timeStep;
    newposition = newposition + 0.5*(oldvelocity + velocity) * timeStep;
    printf("time %f; velocity %f; position %f; new position %f\n", time, velocity, position, newposition);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the results at time = 1.80 seconds for different time steps:

```
step = 0.001: velocity -9.650; position -1.494; new position -1.486
step = 0.010: velocity -9.738; position -1.662; new position -1.573
step = 0.100: velocity -10.62; position -3.420; new position -2.489
```

Finally, the "correct" result from integrating the equations of motion gives

```
velocity = 8 - 1.8*9.8 = -9.64
position = 0 + 8 * 1.8 - 0.5 * 9.8 * 1.8^2 = -1.4760
```

As you can see, smaller steps get better results, and using the "new method" (as suggested by Johannes) gets you closer to the true position than the "lazy method" I first proposed.

**last update**

To implement other forces, you can do something like this:

```
float acceleration, g=9.8, mass=70, drag = 200;
int hasParachute = 1; // set to 0 if no parachute
int onSupport = 1; // set to 0 if not currently stuck on a rock

force = -g * mass;
if(hasParachute == 1) force -= velocity * drag;
if(onSupport) {
  force = 0;
  velocity = 0;
}
acceleration = force / mass;
newvelocity = velocity + timestep * acceleration

... etc
```

I hope you can see how you could implement lots of different things that might change the total force on the object and that will change the motion. In this case, the last term (onSupport) sets both velocity and acceleration to zero, meaning that after a small time step it will still be zero - but if you set `onSupport = 0` it will once again be able to move. And like this you could have multiple objects doing different things under the influence of gravity, rocket packs, etc. You obviously want to experiment with the `drag=200` factor - I just picked a number from thin air, and with a value like 200 you will end up with a terminal velocity of about 3.5 m/s (you would survive that no problem). As you make drag lower, the terminal velocity will be higher (also depends on the mass of the object).

Comment: Thank you so much this helped a lot. I was using AS3 but I can put it into AS3 easily. Also thank you for being straight forward with the answer, most people just write a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the change in velocity is computed as velocity = velocity _minus_ timeStep * g because I use the convention that up = positive, and gravity acceleration points down (negative). You could have used g = -9.8 and a plus sign...

Comment: Yea AS3 everything is backwards hehe. Thanks again

Comment: I got it working thank you :3 .. The only thing I really needed was the velocity but thank you anyways :3

Comment: Also how do I make it stop completely when it hits an object? Iv already tryed turning the velocity to 0 but the timeStep keeps it vibrating so I'm guessing disable the timeStep too?

Comment: If you want it to stop completely you would have to set the acceleration and velocity both to zero (I called the acceleration `g` because it was falling under the influence of gravity, but acceleration could be other things - rockets etc). Setting the `timeStep` to zero would "freeze time" and that's not really right. Especially when you are simulating multiple objects you want to keep time running (so the other objects still move) - that's the more normal scenario.

Comment: but I need "g" to keep my player going down when he falls off an object. is there any other way?

Comment: To address your latest question: you should really compute the acceleration from total force divided by mass. Then $F = -mg + F_{support}+F_{other}$ and $a=\frac{F}{m}$ - this will later allow you to any other forces (parachutes etc). Note that in this case you need to take account of the direction of the forces as you add them up (which is why I wrote `-mg`)

Comment: Sorry for acting like a total noob in physics but how would I emplment  F=−mg+Fsupport+Fother and a=Fm in code? It will help me alot lol ps:I think I need to take physics class lol

Comment: @FlamingPencil - I have answered your question in an edit to my answer. And yes, you need to take some physics classes if you want to become a successful game designer...

Comment: Thanks again I can not explain how much you have helped me in the long run :3 Thx I will leave you alone now lol

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach in numerical simulations is to do a discrete time stepping. If the motion is limited to the vertical direction, you just need to keep track of vertical position $z$ and vertical velocity $v$ (with positive $v$ denoting upward speeds). Starting with given values for $z$ and $v$ (the initial position and initial velocity) you update the position and velocity after each time step as follows:

$$v_{new}=v_{old}-g\Delta t$$
$$z_{new}=z_{old}+\frac12 (v_{new}+v_{old}) \Delta t$$

Here $g$ represents the gravitational acceleration, and $\Delta t$ the step size used in the time stepping.

More advanced time-stepping schemes exist, but I assume this will suffice for a game simulation.

Comment: This is more accurate than the time steps I used in my "good enough for gaming" code...

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I have updated the calculation example in my answer to show that your method works better than the one I originally showed - with attribution, of course.

Comment: @Floris - be my guest!